# DATE_FORMAT mysql django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm currently trying to migrate some MySQL logic to Django (and learning about it in the process). So far the "normal" queries I do understand how to make, but I've hit a wall trying to translate this query into Django "queryset" sintax:

```
SELECT hour, AVG(sessions) 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date, 
    DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%H:00') as hour, COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS sessions
    FROM radacct
    WHERE calledstationid = 'CLIENT' AND acctstarttime < 'DATE'
    GROUP BY date, hour) tb1
GROUP BY hour
```

I can't figure this out, specially the "DATE_FORMAT" part, this query is being used basically to find averages of users per hour over a single table. "CLIENT" and "DATE" are just values I add to the query when executing it. As such it returns something like this:

```
Hour  ---  AVG
00:00 ---  50
01:00 ---  100 
02:00 ---  350
.
.
.
23:00 ---  120
```

This query works as I need to, although I have to admit maybe it's flawed since I am by no means an SQL expert (more like a newbie).

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: So are you asking for Django code here?  Note that many frameworks for MySQL do not support every query.  Sometimes you might need to write a native query.

Comment: Hi, yes exactly, basically if there's a way to translate this into Django sintax

Comment: since you want to work with django I would recommend looking into Postgres. Since you are learning what you also could do is download a Desktop Application to have a look at the tables and rows. You will have a better understanding I can't tell you which one is good for MySQL but for Postgres use http://www.psequel.com

Comment: I don't know but I have upvoted your question.  If you can't find a way to do it within the framework, there should be an option for a native query.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll take into account your recommendation @hansTheFranz. 

Yes I've been reading about raw queries and it seems to be the thing I'll have to use unless I manage to translate this into Django, was actually trying to find out if there's a direct django syntax like this to learn more about it.